# Using an async method in a RxJS NextObserver

Tags: async-await, rxjs, nestjs

I'm trying to use an async function in a NestJS interceptor. These interceptors use RxJS Observables like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    async intercept<T>(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<T>> {
        await doBegin();
        return next
            .handle()
            .pipe(
                tap(
                    () => console.log("Done"),
                    (e) => console.error(e)
                )
            );
    }
}
```

This works, but what if I want the methods in `tap` to be async? The [method signature](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/interface/NextObserver) is:

```
(value: T) => void
```

Can I just put an async method in there? Or should I take a different approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to be async and its error should be caught you need to use `mergeMap` or any other suitable operator to handle it inside of the stream context, because `tap` causes side effects outside of the stream.

```js
const myAsyncFunction = () => {
  // a sample of promise.
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Promise!');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    async intercept<T>(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<T>> {
        await doBegin();
        return next
            .handle()
            .pipe(
                mergeMap(value => from(myAsyncFunction()).pipe(
                  ignoreElements(),
                  // catchError(() => EMPTY), // catching all errors.
                  endWith(value),
                )),
                tap(
                  () => {}, // nothing to do here, we need error.
                  (e) => console.error(e), // or catchError if you wan't to handle it.
                ),
            );
    }
}
```

---

if you don't care about its errors - simply call `.then`.

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    async intercept<T>(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<T>> {
        await doBegin();
        return next
            .handle()
            .pipe(
                tap(
                  myAsyncFunction, // if it returns `new Promise` - it will work.
                  (e) => console.error(e),
                ),
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious how adding the `then()` would help? Doesn't it just return a Promise? Why would it be different from `() => myAsyncFunction()`?

Comment: myAsyncFunction() returns a promise, myAsyncFunction().then() triggers its execution. Depends of course how the promise was written, but to ensure it was really triggered it's better to call `.then`, it's kind of `await Promise`. if it's a correct promise then `myAsyncFunction()` simply returns its pointer but doesn't trigger it.

Comment: Actually you are right and you don't need `.then` in case of `new Promise`. I was confused by my current project :) there we require a `.then` call to trigger original callback.

Comment: I tried this in a local project (without NestJS). Both techniques seem to work, but the mergemap works better IMO. In that case the async function is called before I log the result of the observable stream. In the second case, my async function is executed, but after logging the result of the stream. Because I'm working in AWS Lambda, and I'm not sure if the rest of the event loop will be executed, I'll try the mergeMap technique.

Comment: AWS Lambda will wait for it in both cases, I had with it experience in past. Node has an event loop that checks if there's something to do at some point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ, anyway I would vote for mergeMap too because it has better error handling.